# Weblogic 12c, task in progress forever

Tags: console, weblogic, weblogic12c

I have my domain configured in weblogic 12c. When I try to start servers, they come up(State is changed to Running) and web services are active. However, the Status of Last Action in the weblogic console is always **Task in Progress**

What are the possible reasons that this is not changed to completed.

Also, it gets changed to  **None**  after I restart my Admin.

Answer (score 0):

I would check your AdminServer and Managed servers for any errors. I suspect some communication issues between the Admin and the managed servers